# How to use time.sleep() while running a turtle window?

Tags: python, loops, sleep

When I use `time.sleep()` in a while loop it just pauses the entire turtle window. Is there a different way to pause just inside the loop?

```
while Speed == True:
    time.sleep(5) # <----
    Ball.dx += 0.05
    Ball.dy += 0.05
    if Ball.dx >= 0.030 and Ball.dy >= 0.030: #Here for testing
        break
```

Comment: try using threads and you dont need the == True you can just write while Speed:

Comment: I would suggest the inbuild module threading, it's very easy to use

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
from threading import Thread

# Ball = ...
# Speed = ...

global Ball, Speed

...
def move_ball():
    while Speed == True:
        time.sleep(5)
        Ball.dx += 0.05
        Ball.dy += 0.05

Thread(target=move_ball).start()

# Mainloop here
```